# How to get QSplitter index and position

Tags: python, pyqt

After creating QSplitter with:

```
 splitter=QtGui.QSplitter()
 splitter.addWidget(QtGui.QLabel())
 splitter.addWidget(QtGui.QLabel())
```

the user can costumize the splitter's handle position by just dragging it sidewise.
Every time the application is exited I would like to query Splitter handle position.
This data could be saved into App config file and Splitter settings could be restored using
Splitter's `.moveSplitter(index, pos)` method.

Apparently to use this method I would need the Splitter's `indexes` and their `pos` values. What `QSplitter` attribute/methods should be used to get its indexes and each index's handle `pos` values?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A "snapshot" of `QSplitter`'s current state can be taken using its `.saveState()` method which returns `PyQt4.QtCore.QByteArray` object. Returned QByteArray object can be saved to a disk and retrieved later using `QtCore.QSettings` object. The retrieved Splitter state is assigned "back" to it using its `restoreState()` method.

Example:

```
splitter=QtGui.QSplitter()
iniFile=os.path.join(os.path.expanduser('~'),'myAppName/myAppNameSettings.ini')
settings=QtCore.QSettings(iniFile, QtCore.QSettings.IniFormat)
splitterSettings=splitter.saveState()
if splitterSettings:
    settings.setValue("splitterSettings", splitter.saveState())
```

On app open:

```
settings=QtCore.QSettings(iniFile, QtCore.QSettings.IniFormat)
splitterSettings=settings.value("splitterSettings").toByteArray()
if splitterSettings:
    splitter.restoreState(splitterSettings)
```